# Multiple Video Cards - Stuttering

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have two video cards: 
 
- XFX PVT84JUDD3 GeForce 8600GT XXX 256MB 128-bit GDDR3 PCI Express x16 SLI Supported Video Card 
- EVGA 256-P1-N399-LX GeForce 6200 256MB 64-bit GDDR2 PCI Video Card

both running the same set of drivers on Windows 7 64-bit. When I work with 2 monitors connected to the 8600GT card everything works smoothly. When I connect the third one to the 6200 then Windows works well and all of a suddon the screens halts for up to 5 minutes. Then it goes back and at some random interval it halts again. I can still see the pointer and hit CTRL+ALT+DEL and see the menu to log off, bring the task manager, etc.

I've tried changing the 6200 to another PCI slot and the error persists. I've tried connecting 2 monitors only one to each card, same problem. Tried swapping them, mixed and matched the monitors to see if it was a problem with the monitor and my conclusion was that it is not the monitor.

The problem also occurred with Vista 64 as well.

What could be generating this problem? Can it be the fact that they are different interfaces? Maybe the Motherboard? Should I change something on the BIOS? What do you guys think?

Comment: the 6200 is an ancient GPU by today's standards; you might seriously consider finding another 8600 card if you have an available PCIe slot.

Comment: no more PCIe slots available, need a card with PCI connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your display adapters are different generations, one card is using NVIDIA drivers and the other being treated as plain-jane VESA. The VESA card management is (most likely) being handled by Windows. The NVIDIA drivers are handling the other card. They are not coordinating well.

If you could run two display adapters of the same brand and generation, you may be able to get the manufacturer's drivers to manage them both, and the second (formerly VESA) display adapter will perform better as well.

Comment: Do you think this VC will work with my XFX one? http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814133245

Comment: I think it has a much, much better chance. I would ask on some programming web sites if anyone has a similar combination, and programmers using debuggers (on one monitor) and a GUI (on another) are the most common users of this type.

Comment: Also check your M/B to see if you have a free PCI Express x1 or x4 slot. This will give you better performance and more choices than plain old PCI.

Comment: I do have some free PCIe X1 slots available. What do you recommend? Remember that I'm not a gamer. I just want to have 3/4 monitors for productivity. I'm a programmer.

Comment: The only non-ATI candidate I can find is the PNY VCQ290NVS-PCIEX1-PB Quadro NVS 290 but there may be more out there. It is not a gaming card but should meet your needs. Ideally it would be matched with the same card in its PCIeX16 version.

Comment: the PNY VCG84512SPEB GeForce 8400 GS 512MB 64-bit GDDR2 PCI Low Profile Ready Video Card did the trick.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks for the accepted answer. You might also consider an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS, you can set which is the primary card. It was pretty helpful to deal with some problems in Linux. You may want to try some combinations and see if it helps.